# What is the cost of a +1 Mithral Heavy Steel Shield?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, shield, pricing, special-materials

I need a breakdown of the item costs:

Base price
Mithral
+1 Enchantment

I’ve read that there have been conflicting prices between the Core Rulebook and Ultimate Equipment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### A +1 mithral heavy shield should have a market price of 2,020 gp.

I checked both the *Core Rulebook* (6th printing, 2013), *Ultimate Equipment* (2nd printing, 2012), as well as the [Pathfinder d20 SRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral). All of them have the same information about arms and armor made of mithral. I've quoted the relevant parts below:

> Spell failure chances for armors and shields made from mithral are decreased by 10%, maximum Dexterity bonuses are increased by 2, and armor check penalties are decreased by 3 (to a minimum of 0).
>
> An item made from mithral weighs half as much as the same item made from other metals.
>
> ...
>
> Weapons and armors fashioned from mithral are always masterwork items as well; the masterwork cost is included in the prices given below.
>
> ...
>
> Shield +1,000 gp

**Calculating the price and stats:**

First we start with the 20gp base cost of a [heavy steel shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/), because it's metal like mithral. Then we add the mithral cost of +1000gp, which means it already counts as masterwork. Finally, the shield gets a [+1 enhancement bonus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/) that increases its price by another +1000gp.

The total price is **2020gp**. The shield weighs 7.5 lb for a medium-sized creature, or 3.75 lb for a small-sized creature. It has an armor check penalty of -0, and 
a 5% arcane spell failure chance.

Comment: As for the source  of the question's  confusion: The first printing of *Ultimate Equipment* (Aug. 2012) says on page 151 that the Item Price Modifier of a mithral shield is +1,500 gp. Later printings corrected this error?

Comment: The price of mithral in Ultimate Equipment was corrected in the second printing. "Page 51—In mithral, in the price table, change the shield price modifier from “+1,500 gp” to “+1,000 gp”."